# Which bluetooth gamepads are compatible with RetroPie?

Tags: retropie, gamepad, games

I want to set up a RasPi 3 for games with RetroPie. I have a WiFi and a Bluetooth dongle (BT 4.0) and now would like to buy one or two BT gamepads. Which are useful and/or compatible and of good quality for use with the RetroPie system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running "Sixaxis" PS3 controller on RetroPi (RPi 3). In the beginning i had some trouble but following this [tutorial](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Setting-up-a-PS3-controller) i could pair the controller without issues. They are working great with the RetroPi.

On this Github site is a list of other controllers and how connect them to the RetroPi. But mostly there are no comments how good they are working later.

Imho the PS3 controller feels little bit more laggy than on the PS3. This is my very subjective experience... maybe this would disappear with some tweaks.

Comment: Where is the GitHub list of supported controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Im using a fake bluetooth ps3 controller I bought from a second hand store for $10. I think its called a dragon pad. It works well. The only difference is hand feel. There a few differences. The fake feels lighter and when moving the analog sticks they dont move as smoothly as an official controller. But these differences are hardly noticeable.